# How to fix Sonar error "not construct the path from user-controlled data"?

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-11, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I am getting the Sonar error

> *Change this code to not construct the path from user-controlled data.*

Already added a validation before using `fileName` inside `OutputStream`.

Below is the code I am using:

```
if (Util.isValidFileName(fileName)) {
    try (FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
    }
}

public static boolean isValidFileName(String filePath) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[/\\:*?\"<>|]");
    if (filePath == null || filePath.trim().isEmpty() || pattern.matcher(filePath).find()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid file destination path");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also tried something like below but getting same Sonar error.

```
if(!FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName).contains("exe")) {
    try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
    }
}
```

Please suggest how can I add the validation to resolve this sonar error.

Comment: How do you create the `fileName` variable?